# Unable to execute child_process.exec() when path has spaces

Tags: node.js, shell-exec

I am using <strike>appjs *</strike> and I want to execute a command to open a folder.

### What I have

```
var path = __dirname + '/folder to open/'; 
// path = C:\Program Files\myapplication/folder to open/
require("child_process").exec("start " + path);
```

### Error

> Could not find file C:\Program

### What I tried

I already tried to escape the spaces, that didn't work.

```
var path = __dirname + '/folder to open/'; 
path = path.replace(' ', '\ ');
// path = C:\Program Files\myapplication/folder to open/
require("child_process").exec("start " + path);
```

When I put the path between quotes, No folder is opened, only another prompt.

```
var path = "\"" + __dirname + "/folder to open/\"";
path = path.replace(' ', '\ ');
// path = "C:\Program Files\myapplication/folder to open/"
require("child_process").exec("start " + path);
```

Related bug https://github.com/isaacs/npm/pull/2479

Does anyone has a fix or a workaround?

* link removed

Comment: Escape spaces? `path = path.replace(' ', '\ ');` Make path a string? `path = '"/path to open/"';

Comment: try putting the path in quotes

Comment: Escaping spaces doesn't work :( also, path already is a string.

Comment: There is an even worst scenario where you can't actually workaround. I'm trying to spawn the execution of "npm" and as npm is installed in "Program Files" (space here) it won't work. I even tried modifying the %PATH% variable by adding "" to the begging and end of every path and that didn't worked neither :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I fixed it.

Or something like it.

Instead of using

`"start " + path`

I used

`"%SystemRoot%\\explorer.exe \"" + path + "\""`

Notice the quotes and the forward slashes.

Answer (score 20):

To open a path than contains spaces, you must replace with a double backslash.

In your code you escaped the space character:

```
"\ "
```

What you need to do is escape the backslash character so it makes it into the output string:

```
"\\ "
```

Try this:

```
var path = __dirname + '/folder to open/'; 

// Notice the double-backslashes on this following line
path = path.replace(/ /g, '\\ ');

require("child_process").exec("start " + path);
```

Comment: Is this solution cross-platform?

Comment: @Michael, I have not tested whether it is cross-platform. I would doubt it worked for every platform.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it is fixed by adding double quotes for the path except the first drive name or letter.

```
import * as path from 'path'; // npm module
const filePath = 'C:/Program Files/my application/file to open/test.txt';

const rootName = path.parse(filePath).root; // "C:/"

const filePathTo = `${rootName}"${filePath.replace(rootName, '')}"`; // C:/"Program Files/my application/file to open/test.txt"  

require("child_process").exec(`start ${filePathTo}`);
```

The text file will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
f= file.replace(/ /g,"\\\ ")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the old-style 8-character-max/no-space names for each path.

The one I always used was always coding `c:\PROGRA~1` instead of `c:\Program Files`, although this only works on english systems.

If the first 8 characters of any path with more chars are unique, I expect you can do something like `newPath = origPath.sub(/\W/g, '').substr(0, 6) + "~1"`

Don't have a windows system here, just going by memory.